# How can I run a chronometer on my django host webpage?

Tags: javascript, django

I'm trying to insert a chronometer into my webpage, so that when a button is clicked they will have certain time to solve certain challenges. This chronometer should be unique for the hole server (anyone who can get inside will see this chronometer) and it has to be global for all the views in my web. I'm using Django.

I can't find information about this, I know how to make chronometer, but how can I run it on my server and put it on all the views of my website. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the code with us you've tried so far? That way we can help you debug it.

Comment: Take a look at Django template tags for getting the datetime into all of your views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags   As far as saving it to the server, that probably depends on how often it should change. Could be an env variable or constant if it rarely change, otherwise could be a simple Class to save the datetime to the db, then update as necessary.